# Trouble implementing generic OrderBy solution

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

I have a method that takes `IQueryable<T>` and I want to implement OrderBy generically inside it. Ideally by passing in `c => c.SomeProperty` in as a parameter but I can't figure out how to get the generics working on that so I've tried it with a string. However I am getting the error:

```
Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration
```

This is what I tried (using the string method)

```
var sortSelectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
var sortSelector = Expression.PropertyOrField(sortSelectorParameter, "ClientId"); // ClientId is the property string

collection = collection.OrderByDescending(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(sortSelector));
```

I am very confused as OrderBy only takes one parameter - any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the parameter to `Expression::Lambda<T>`, as the error says:

```
var sortSelectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
var sortSelector = Expression.PropertyOrField(sortSelectorParameter, "ClientId"); // ClientId is the property string

collection = collection.OrderByDescending(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(sortSelector, sortSelectorParameter ));
```

Your "body" for the lambda refers to a parameter `c`, which is represented by the `ExpressionParameter` instance `sortSelectorParameter`. You need to pass this parameter instance to the lambda, so that it knows that the parameter referred to by the body is in fact the in-parameter of the lambda you wish to create.

EDIT: The above may answer your technical question, but it is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. If you just want to order by something which you know at compile-time, then you don't need any of this. What is the point of wrapping the `OrderByDescending`-method?

```
IQueryable<TElement> MySpecialOrderBy<TElement, TKey>(IQueryable<TElement> source, Expression<Func<TElement, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense. Would you happen to know how I can pass the parameter in as `c => c.SomeParam` instead of "SomeParam"?

Comment: This will throw an exception, unless the type of `ClientId` is `bool`

Comment: @NibblyPig If it is generic without constraints, then you can't. How would it know in compile-time that `T` would have a property `SomeParam`? You could declare a constraint on the type parameter `T` with some interface which has `SomeParam` as a property and use that.

Comment: If you know that you would like to sort on `c.SomeParam`, you wouldn't need the expressions. You need to pass `"SomeParam"` as string.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten it will also fail if there is no public property or field called "ClientId", but that is not in the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I know what I am passing into the method, only the inside of the method doesn't know, this is how generics works.

Comment: My code doesn't work because it doesn't like the `bool` part of `Func<T, bool>` since my property can be of all kinds of types, should it be `object`?

Comment: So why did you put `bool` there? We need more context, why are you wrapping the order-by in this method?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite complex:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByDescending = (from x in typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                                        where x.Name == "OrderByDescending"
                                                        let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                                        where args.Length == 2
                                                        let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                                        where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                                            pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                                                            pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(args))
                                                        select x).Single();

public static IQueryable<T> OrderByStringDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string parameter)
{
    var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
    var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(par, parameter);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(selector, par);
    return (IQueryable<T>)OrderByDescending.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), selector.Type).Invoke(null, new object[] { query, lambda });
}
```

You have to build an `Expression.Lambda`. The problem is that invoking the `Queryable.OrderByDescending` (that has **two** parameters, the `IQueryable<>` query and the `Expression<>`) without knowing the `TKey` type at compile time is complex. I solve it through reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to pass an expression the some method that does other stuff with the collection then it's easy:

```
public void Test<T,TKey>(IQueryable<T> collection, Expression<Func<T,TKey>> orderByExpr)
{
    // your logic here 
    // ...
    collection = collection.OrderByDescending(orderByExpr);
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
this.Test(collection, c => c.ClientId);
```