# When using a Lambda Expression to perform an OrderBy on a generic collection, integer properties cause an exception

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6, expression

I have:

`IQueryable<T> collection`

```
var sortSelectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
var sortSelector = GetPropertyOrField<T>(sortSelectorParameter, "SomeId");

collection = collection.OrderByDescending(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(sortSelector, sortSelectorParameter));
```

This works fine if the parameter (SomeId) is a string. However if it's an integer (or presumably other types as well) then I get an exception saying it cannot convert int to an object.

If I try an `Expression.Convert` I get another exception later on saying entity framework cannot convert it to a string as it doesn't support conversions.

If I change `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>` to `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>` then it works perfectly but only for integer properties.

I am not sure how to make it support all types with some monstrous switch statement. Can anyone offer any advice on this?

Comment: My guess would be related to Nullable objects and non-Nullable objects.
Have you tried with ```int?``` instead of ```int```?

Comment: Many thanks for finding the answer, it was a hard question to search for

Comment: @NibblyPig You can't use `object` for the `TKey`. Use for example the response I gave you in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/43369404/613130) that extract the key type and generates an `Expression<>` of the right type.

Comment: And this is like your fifth question about `Expression<>` trees you do in 24h, trying to rebuild Dynamic Linq... [There is a perfect good source for Dynamic Linq, it is 2500 lines long and a single file](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/master/Src/System.Linq.Dynamic/DynamicLinq.cs).